# MS Excel formula for computing total in years, months, and days

Tags: excel, formula

How do I calculate the total of Year Month and Days as given snapshot.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `SUM()` function?

Comment: @harun24hr SUM() wont work here, in days above 30 days should be added with Months total and same Months answer if morethan 12 should be added with Years total as well.

Comment: Please try my answer and feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment try following formulas.

For days `=MOD(SUM(D2:D7),30)` 
For months `=MOD(SUM(C2:C7)+INT(SUM(D2:D7)/30),12)` 
For years `=SUM(B2:B7)+INT((INT(SUM(D2:D7)/30)+SUM(C2:C7))/12)`

[image]